# Invalid CastException Was Unhandled

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, facebook-c#-sdk

I am getting the following error when trying to run code from http://facebooksdk.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/facebook-groups.html

The error is "Invalid CastException Was Unhandled" and "Specified Cast Is Not Valid"

I am using the Facebook C# SDK and I am using the following code...

```
    public Dictionary<string, string> GetGroups()
    {
        string accessToken = _accessToken;
        FacebookClient facebookClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
        JsonObject resul = facebookClient.Get("https://graph.facebook.com/me/groups?access_token=" + accessToken) as JsonObject;
        Dictionary<string, string> dicGroups = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (JsonObject item in (((KeyValuePair<string, object>)(resul[0])).Value as JsonArray))
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(item["id"].ToString());
        }
        return dicGroups;
    }
```

Could anyone help? I am trying to get a list of all the users groups and add them to a combobox. Thanks

Comment: Which line of code is throwing the exception?

Comment: It is telling you exactly what you need to know - You're casting an object to a different type than it is. I'm assuming it's inside the foreach, where you cast your `resul[0]` as `KeyValuePair<string, object>`

Comment: Its inside the foreach, but I am new to C# and just need to know how to fix it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the Facebook C# SDK more, and the api returns a json string of groups. You need to loop through each object in the json string to get what you want.

```
JsonObject groups = facebookClient.Get("me/groups") as JsonObject;
foreach(var group in (JsonArray)groups["data"])
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(item["id"].ToString());
    ...
}
```

Note: You need to prompt the user for the `user_groups` extended permission to be able to retrieve groups. Follow [this link](http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Writing-your-first-Facebook-Application.aspx) for an example of prompting for extended permissions. I don't have a Facebook app, so I can't test prompting for the permissions and retrieving group information.

Comment: Dave Zych, do I need to add any reference or anything to that? I tried that and it says the namespace JsonValue is not available. Sorry if I sound like a noob

Comment: @PhilipDanks - Have you even tired?